# Late 80s/early 90s matrix printer with a solid, curved front cover

Tags: printer, identify-this-peripheral

I am trying to remember the exact year but I am drawing a blank. We had this matrix printer sometime between 1989 and 1994 in Hungary. What I distinctly remember is the front cover: it was solid, not opaque and it was not flat, it was a curved shape. I think there were noise dampening inserts inside it, just pieces of foam glued in. Most certainly it was parallel, Centronics, likely 9 pins.

Comment: Try searching for images of "early dot matrix printers", or "vintage dot matrix printers". Perhaps something will ring a bell.

Comment: Centronix? Must've been an import then. I would be interested to know, was this printer imported before or after the rendszerváltás?

Comment: We had the [Star LC200](https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com/v1/files/cs31oyrm203i2-PL/image;s=644x461) which likely means that a lot of people did; I’ll wager there’s a thousand models that fit your description though.

Comment: I also had the Star LC200-series; maybe LC210 or LC220

Comment: @OmarandLorraine I am fairly sure it's after. We had a ZX Spectrum then a SAM Coupé, then an IBM PC clone and the Speccy didn't have a printer interface while I do remember getting a custom cable made which only makes sense for the SAM. So that means 1990 at the earliest given when the SAM was released. But it's possible it was later because if memory serves we had the SAM and the PC XT clone both at the same time for quite a while. That's why I remember the Centronics interface...

Comment: @Tommy a) that's opaque, this was not b) think of sea waves. This is not round enough by far.

Comment: @chx if you think that’s opaque then your definition of opaque may need some adjustment. Amongst other details you can see through that lid, the printer ribbon is currently centred. Since you can see through it, it falls into the category used by the question of “not opaque”.

Comment: As soon as I saw "not flat" and "not opaque" I too thought of the Star series (LC-100 is pretty much identical). However, brown/grey translucent covers were rather common indeed in this era, and while most were flat, I'm sure Star wasn't the only one.

Comment: "Most certainly it was parallel, Centronics, likely 9 pins." That doesn't make sense. The original Centronics connector was a 36-pins one (with a whole lot of spare or redundant pins). But 9 pins simple aren't enough for Centronics. If it really was a 9-pin connector, I'd guess it was serial (RS-232).

Comment: @chx, it's interesting to see that the Sam Coupe sold abroad as well as in the UK, I had no idea really. We had such high hopes for it pre-launch and then that nice 6 MHz Z80B turned out to be speed-limited well below 6 MHz in its non-Spectrum modes, plus it cost so much. Were you in Hungary when you bought it?

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff - I think he means the pins in the print head, not the pins in the connector. A period is missing.

Comment: Yeah, I meant the print head.